# Effect of gravity on height of a person

Tags: newtonian-gravity, biophysics, geophysics

My physics teacher told us (while teaching the topic gravitation) that gravity has a effect on height of human body, he gave us following examples:

1. The height of astronauts after coming back to earth is found to be increased slightly.
2. The people living at equator (such as in west indies) are usually found longer than people living in polar countries (as value of $g$ differ at pole and equator). {This example seems quite interesting and I have a doubt in it}.

His examples were quite interesting and also confusing (as I am unable to get the reason behind them), but I suppose I can get the answer here. I hope for an answer  which may describe the relation between gravity and height of a person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The human body is somewhat elastic (a good property to have, otherwise we would break bones more frequently) and as with any elastic body it will tend to stretch or compress when subjected to a force. Gravity is such a force. When we stand upright, the force of gravity compresses us and makes us a little shorter. If we measured our height while hanging by our heels, the effect would be opposite and we would be somewhat taller.

As for the observation that people living at or near the equator tend to be taller than those living near the polar regions, I would doubt that that (if true) is due to gravity.  The gravitational effect is probably too small to dominate over other factors such as genetics and nutritional effects.

Comment: Sorry if the question doesn't seems meaningful but can't we say that contribution of gravity over many generation can't be neglected.

Comment: $TheLoneWolf Of course gravity has influenced our evolution, but the difference in g is very small over the surface of our planet. Food sources are scarce in polar regions so nutrition has probably been poorer in those regions.

Answer (score 1):

Astronauts experiencing microgravity in space have indeed been found to return to Earth a few centimeters taller than when they left. Some studies conducted have indicated that microgravity affects the spinal vertebrae, allowing them to expand and relax more easily than when under the effect of the Earth's gravity (where the greater gravitational force of the Earth pulls the spine downwards, compressing the vertebrae). It is worth noting that these changes in height quickly dissapear upon return to Earth as the spine becomes once again compressed.

As for people around the equator, as far as I know they have grown taller primarily through natural selection, with weaker gravity playing a small or negligible role (although I may be proven wrong!). Typically people living in areas around the equator - many African people for example - have diets high in animal proteins, allowing them to grow taller, whereas animal proteins in the north and south pole are scarce!

See this link for further information on the effects of microgravity on the spine:
http://www.space.com/19116-astronauts-taller-space-spines.html

Comment: Thanks @acernine for the good answer and for the website you mentioned,i was searching for one like it

Comment: You are correct on the effect of diet. Take the average height of Japanese before and after the war http://nbakki.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/05/30/173407   http://www.naturalheightgrowth.com/2012/10/13/the-changing-body-and-increase-in-height-of-japanese-women-and-girls-in-the-last-century/  Seems to be the introduction of dairy products to the diet.

Answer (score 1):

Consider and *extremely* simplified model of a human as say a spring with a mass at the top, where the spring is some representation of your muscular joints/backbone etc. that keeps you up. Because of a gravitational force, the equilibrium height of the mass of the spring will be somewhat lower than the natural length of the spring. This deviation will increase in an increasing gravitational field.

In the same way, being in a weaker gravitational field will allow your backbone etc to stretch out a little more because there isn't as much of a force opposing it.

That being said, I highly doubt that there would be any measurable difference in the average height of people living at the equator and people living near the poles. The astronaut example I believe, and I'm quite sure is true, but I would be very skeptical of the equator vs polar country example being attributed to the difference in the effective gravitational field.

Comment: +1 for  good answer,but it is observable that there is a difference between height at pole and equator.

Comment: @THE LONE WOLF - have you corrected for dietary and genetic differences in the sample populations?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick,i agree that diet,and natural selection may be  the reason behind  he height difference,but the question i m pointing out is that"is gravity one of the factors which can explain this difference in height".

Comment: @THE LONE WOLF Are expatriates noted for complaining that their trousers no longer fit them? I suspect any difference due to gravity is negligible compared to [other factors](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1545095/).

Comment: The difference in gravitational acceleration between the equator and the poles is only around 0.5%. (Source -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth#Latitude). That is far too minor to make any observable difference that would appear outside the error and deviations due to the several several other effects.

Comment: maybe i m going wrong but let's continue the argument,the astronaut do not live in space throughout their life and in the small period(not so small) they gain 3% of their height,then why a  gravity difference of 0.5% can't make a difference in the complete life.

Comment: An astronaut faces changes in gravitational acceleration of almost 100%. That's 200 times greater than the difference observed by people across countries. Far more importantly, in the astronaut case, you can measure the same persons height before and after his trip. It is meaningful to make such a comparison because any control experiment of a person on earth at the same age would not increase significantly in height. There is no such experiment you can easily setup for the case of different latitudes to observe differences across several years because all the other factors come into play too.

Answer (score 1):

The differences are very small but being in the presence of stronger gravity will compress your body a little more than what weaker gravity would do. The body isn't a completely rigid structure (ie. diamond) so like the other poster mentioned it's kind of like a spring. The more force you apply to the spring the shorter it will be.